# Can’t enter insert mode in Vi editor

Tags: 12.04, vi

I am using the Vi editor on my desktop Ubuntu 12.04, and do no have any problems. But a few days ago, I installed the Vi editor to my beagleboard-xm which has both Angstrom and Ubuntu 12.04 available but noticed that I cannot activate the insert mode at both of the Op. Systems. How I understood that:

When I press <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>I</kbd>, I do not get a warning on the bottom, just `-- INSERT --`. But if I continue and if I press <kbd>k</kbd>, the cursor moves to the line above, and if I press <kbd>j</kbd>, the cursor moves to the line below. If I try to put a <kbd>#</kbd> to comment out something, the cursor moves randomly and according to warning written at the bottom: "search hit TOP, continuing at BOTTOM", etc. etc.

How can I get into insert mode? Any suggestions?

Comment: open vi and try to set `:set showmode`. Then try "Esc - i(insert mode)"

Comment: @devav2 I tried what you suggested, first at the bottom -- INSERT -- warning has written but when I pressed the arrow keys that warning disappeared and same behavior continues.

Answer (score 4):

Try the <kbd>a</kbd> key for the same -- INSERT -- operation. It should work just like <kbd>i</kbd>. AFAIK, it works on Ubuntu 12.04 and Raspbian.

Comment: It's not "just like [i]" — [a] starts insertion _after_ current character, while [i] inserts _before_ current character.

Answer (score 2):

Install Vim as it is an improved version of vi.

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

To open a file with vim, you have to use vim command insteat of vi

```
vim abc.txt
```

Comment: Even though your answer will work, it would be nice to know, *why* you suggest to install it.

Comment: Just because, vim is an improved version, Simple.

Comment: I know. I meant it as a suggestion on how to improve your answer. Please, hit the edit link on your answer and add the information there.

Answer (score 1):

first of all install  this command in your ubuntu prompt :

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

then after work the insert mode.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this does, and why you believe it to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems, but they successfully resolved when I noticed default keymap not EN.

Since that I use <kbd>Insert</kbd>  and have no problems.